# CSS: Align column in table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry for dumb question. I am new to css. I have following UI:

[image]

I have following code:

```
<div class="row centered-form center-block">
                <div class="container col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h4><span class="label label-default">Hello</span></h4>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <h4><span class="label label-success">World</span></h4>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h4><span class="label label-default">Hello Hello</span></h4>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <h4><span class="label label-success">World World</span></h4>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <h4><span class="label label-default">Hello Hello Hello</span></h4>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <h4><span class="label label-success">World World World</span></h4>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    <br/>

                    <div class="row centered-form center-block">
                        <div class="container col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                            <div class="form-inline">
                                <div class="form-group" style="width: 40%;">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default">
                                        Hello
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group" style="width: 40%;">
                                    <button class="btn btn-default">
                                        World
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I tried different approaches and didn't succeed. I meet align problems all the time. Please show me effective way of managing alignments in CSS. I would like to align everything by green lines, accordingly left column is `right-aligned` and right column `left-aligned`.

Comment: how do you want it to look, your question is not clear

Comment: Tables should only be used for tabular data - not layout

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I added details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Pete's comment that tables shouldn't be used for layout but if you continue then you can use the following styles:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
td:nth-child(odd) { /* every first column in the 2 column table */
  padding-right: 50px;  /* this is for that gap down the middle */
  text-align: right; /* align the column to the right */
}
td:nth-child(even) { /* every second column in the 2 column table */
  padding-left: 50px; /* this is for that gap down the middle */
  text-align: left; /* align the column to the left */
}
td {
  width: 50%; /* equal width columns */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h4><span class="label label-default">Hello</span></h4>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4><span class="label label-success">World</span></h4>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h4><span class="label label-default">Hello Hello</span></h4>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4><span class="label label-success">World World</span></h4>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <h4><span class="label label-default">Hello Hello Hello</span></h4>
    </td>
    <td>
      <h4><span class="label label-success">World World World</span></h4>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution for efficiently aligning columns in a table that works for me. Requires Jquery and bootstrap...

Put this script in down the bottom of the page:

```
<script>
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $(".col" + i + "r th:nth-of-type(" + i + ")").addClass("text-right");
    $(".col" + i + "r td:nth-of-type(" + i + ")").addClass("text-right");
    $(".col" + i + "c th:nth-of-type(" + i + ")").addClass("text-center");
    $(".col" + i + "c td:nth-of-type(" + i + ")").addClass("text-center");
    }
</script>
```

Assign classes in the table tag using this syntax:

"col"+colnumber+align

eg. col2r = column 2 right align (column 1 is left column)

eg. col3c = column 3 center align

left align is a default align, so no need to cover this off here.

eg.

class="table col2r col3c"
or 
class="table col2c col3r"

Note: th is included here. 10 is the number of columns.. adjust accordingly.

Here's a fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/kcwbhczy/